# Print edges that connect a SCC to another SCC

Tags: c, graph, tarjans-algorithm

I am currently doing a project where i need to find how many *strongly connected components* (SCC) exist on a graph and, after that, i need to check if there are *any edges going from any SCC to another SCC*.

I'm using Tarjan's algorithm and i can already get all the SCC from a given graph, but i can't compute the next part.

I had two ideas:

1. Delete all edges inside every SCC. The only ones left would be the possible candidates.
2. Somehow turn every SCC to a "vertex", or a super vertex, and then check if there are any outgoing connections to any other super vertex.

The only constraints i have are:

- If there is more than one connection to the same SCC, i only need to display it once;
- When i display the connection, i need to display always the smallest vertex id belonging to the SCC, whether it's the outgoing SCC or incoming SCC.

A little example:

**Input as *edge from x to y***

1 2; 2 3; 3 1; 2 4; 4 5; 5 4;

Here's an [image of the above graph](http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/18/0321/h_1521649489_8942456_e8bcd10dba.png), where 1 = A, 2 = B and so forth...

My question is: How can i compute this? Every option i seem to come up with, seems like it will be too time and resources consuming.

Appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Might want to pick a language. C and C++ are distinct, e.g. Boost::graph is pointless for C.

Comment: Thanks! yes, they are, but im using a mix of them, just for convinience. But i'll change it to C :)